# How do I perform math operations on dates and sort them in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, date

I have dates in a Python script that I need to work with that are in a list. I have to keep the format that already exists. The format is YYYY-MM-DD. They are displayed in the form ['2010-05-12', '2011-04-15', 'Date', '2010-04-20', '2010-11-05'] where the order of the dates appears to be random and they are made into lists with seemingly insignificant lengths. The length of this data can get very large. I need to know how to sort these dates into a chronological order and omit the seemingly randomly placed entries of 'Date' from this order. Then I need to be able to perform math operations such as moving up and down the list. For example if I have five dates in order I need to be able to take one date and be able to find a date x spaces ahead or behind that date in the order. I'm very new to Python so simpler explanations and implementations are preferred. Let me know if any clarifications are needed. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to keep them in that format? Convert them to datetime.date objects and format them for display.

Comment: I don't need to keep this format if I can convert it back.

Comment: If your format is always `YYYY-MM-DD` (i.e. not influenced by the current [locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale)), then the [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) is the same as the chronological order.  Just sort them as strings!

Comment: It's good to know that I can sort them as strings but how do I do this and arrange them properly in chronological order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking several questions at the same time, so I'll answer them in order.

To filter out the `"Date"` entries, use the [`filter` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) like this:

```
dates = ['2011-06-18', 'Date', '2010-01-13', '1997-12-01', '2007-08-11']
dates_filtered = filter(lambda d: d != 'Date', dates)
```

Or perhaps like this, using [Python's list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), if you find it easier to understand:

```
dates_filtered = [d for d in dates if d != 'Date']
```

You might want to convert the data types of the date items in your list to the [`date` class](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects) to get access to some date-related methods like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_objects = [datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for x in dates_filtered]
```

And to sort the dates you simply use the [`sort` method](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
date_objects.sort()
```

The syntax in Python for accessing items and ranges of items in lists (or any "sequence type") is quite powerful. You can [read more about it here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). For example, if you want to access the last two dates in your list you could do something like this:

```
print(date_objects[-2:]
```

If you put it all together you'll get something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = ['2011-06-18', 'Date', '2010-01-13', '1997-12-01', '2007-08-11']
my_dates = [datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            for d in dates
            if d != 'Date']
my_dates.sort()
```

Comment: That sounds like what I want to do. So how do I go about doing this?

Comment: I added some examples and links to the Python documentation. (Which is great, and you should really get to know your way around it if you are going to do any serious Python programming). The examples above is probably not exactly how I would actually write the code, I just wanted to show you how to get started in a simple way. Happy coding!

Comment: As a side note, the examples above will actually work if you cut and paste them into a text file. They are Python 2.[something] as well as Python 3 compatible.